# Remove vertical space between title and first line of own "table of"

Tags: spacing, koma-script, tocloft

I try to reduce the space between the head and the first line of my own "table of". I found several solutions for table of content and other standard "table ofs". But somehow they do not work with my own created "table of".
Here is my minimal example:

```
\documentclass[oneside, a4paper, 12pt]{scrreprt}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\listequationsname}{Formelverzeichnis}
\newlistof{myequations}{equ}{\listequationsname}
\newcommand{\myequations}[1]{%
\addcontentsline{equ}{myequations}{\protect\numberline{\theequation}#1}\par}
\listofmyequations
\begin{equation}\label{eq:Hamming-Distanz}
    dist_{H}(v,w) = count_{i}(v_{i} \neq w_{i} ) 
\end{equation}
\myequations{Abstandasmaß: Hamming-Distanz}
\end{document}
```

I already tried following solutions (which did not work):

- `\setlength{\cftbeforemyequationstitleskip}{-3em}`
- `\addtocontents{myequations}{\protect\enlargethispage{\baselineskip}}`
- `\addtocontents{myequations}{\vskip -1.2cm}`
- `\setlength\cftaftermyequationstitleskip{-3pt}`

When you can tell me what I have to do to reduce the space, please remember I am a Latex beginner.
Thank you for your help.
Kind regards.
Matthias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not recommended to use `titlesec` and `tocloft` together with a KOMA-Script class. You can use the possibilities of `tocbasic` to create a new list. The package `tocbasic` is part of the KOMA-Script bundle and `scrreprt` loads `tocbasic` automatically.

```
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\DeclareNewTOC[
  type=equation,
  tocentryindent=1.5em
]{equ}
\newcaptionname{ngerman}{\equationname}{Gleichung}
\newcaptionname{ngerman}{\listequationname}{Formelverzeichnis}
\newcommand\myequation[1]{\addxcontentsline{equ}{equation}[\theequation]{#1}}
```

Then your new list has the same layout as the standard lists.

If you really want to remove the space after the title only for this single list you can use

```
\BeforeTOCHead[equ]{\RedeclareSectionCommand[afterskip=0pt]{chapter}}
```

If this should be done for all TOC remove `[equ]` from this line.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrreprt}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\DeclareNewTOC[
  type=equation,
  tocentryindent=1.5em
]{equ}
\newcaptionname{ngerman}{\equationname}{Gleichung}
\newcaptionname{ngerman}{\listequationname}{Formelverzeichnis}
\newcommand\myequation[1]{\addxcontentsline{equ}{equation}[\theequation]{#1}}

%\BeforeTOCHead[equ]{\RedeclareSectionCommand[afterskip=0pt]{chapter}}

\begin{document}
\listofequations
\listoffigures
\chapter{Kapitel}
Text
\begin{equation}
    \myequation{Abstandsmaß: Hamming-Distanz}
    \label{eq:Hamming-Distanz}
    dist_{H}(v,w) = count_{i}(v_{i} \neq w_{i} ) 
\end{equation}

\begin{center}
  \rule{6cm}{2cm}
  \captionof{figure}{test}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Using also

```
\BeforeTOCHead[equ]{\RedeclareSectionCommand[afterskip=0pt]{chapter}}
```

results in

[image]

---

Update: With KOMA-Script version 3.20 option `tocentryindent` has replaced `indent` in the argument of `\DeclareNewTOC`. So I have updated this in the code above.

Comment: Hey, I tried your solution and it looks great. Thank you very much.