# Own "Table of" increase space between section number and text beginning

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents

in following question is a "Table of equations" I implemented.
[Remove vertical space between title and first line of own "table of"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270603/remove-vertical-space-between-title-and-first-line-of-own-table-of)
But unfortunately the space between the section number and the first letter of the line is so small that they overlay.
[image]
Can you tell me how to increase the space?
Thank you very much.

Comment: you can try `\DeclareNewTOC[
  type=equation,
  indent=1.5em,hang=2em%or 2.5em
]{equ}`

Comment: Ha, that was it. Thank you very much! Why don't you post it as answer to get a correct answer?

Comment: @touhami: Please turn your comment into an answer

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Done.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution. One need to use option `hang`

```
\DeclareNewTOC[type=equation, indent=1.5em, hang=2.5em]{equ}
```

**WE**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\DeclareNewTOC[
  type=equation,
  indent=1.5em,
  hang=2.5em
  ]{equ}

\newcaptionname{ngerman}{\equationname}{Gleichung}
\newcaptionname{ngerman}{\listequationname}{Formelverzeichnis}
\newcommand\myequation[1]{\addxcontentsline{equ}{equation}[\theequation]{#1}}

\begin{document}
\listofequations
\chapter{Kapitel}

\setcounter{equation}{20}
Text
\begin{equation}
    \myequation{Abstandsmaß: Hamming-Distanz A}
    \label{eq:Hamming-DistanzA}
    dist_{H}(v,w) = count_{i}(v_{i} \neq w_{i} ) 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    \myequation{Abstandsmaß: Hamming-Distanz B}
    \label{eq:Hamming-DistanzB}
    dist_{H}(v,w) = count_{i}(v_{i} \neq w_{i} ) 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    \myequation{Abstandsmaß: Hamming-Distanz C}
    \label{eq:Hamming-DistanzC}
    dist_{H}(v,w) = count_{i}(v_{i} \neq w_{i} ) 
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ;-)))))))))))))))))) (+1)